# Searching in JSON list

Tags: python

I have this JSON code:

```
{"intents": [
        {"tag": "greeting",
         "patterns": ["Hi", "How are you", "Is anyone there?", "Hello", "Good day"],
         "responses": ["Hello, thanks for visiting", "Good to see you again", "Hi there, how can I help?"],
         "context_set": ""
        },
        {"tag": "goodbye",
         "patterns": ["Bye", "See you later", "Goodbye"],
         "responses": ["See you later, thanks for visiting", "Have a nice day", "Bye! Come back again soon."]
        },
        {"tag": "thanks",
         "patterns": ["Thanks", "Thank you", "That's helpful"],
         "responses": ["Happy to help!", "Any time!", "My pleasure"]
        },
        {"tag": "hours",
         "patterns": ["What hours are you open?", "What are your hours?", "When are you open?" ],
         "responses": ["We're open every day 9am-9pm", "Our hours are 9am-9pm every day"]
        },
        {"tag": "payments",
         "patterns": ["Do you take credit cards?", "Do you accept Mastercard?", "Are you cash only?" ],
         "responses": ["We accept VISA, Mastercard and AMEX", "We accept most major credit cards"]
        },
        {"tag": "opentoday",
         "patterns": ["Are you open today?", "When do you open today?", "What are your hours today?"],
         "responses": ["We're open every day from 9am-9pm", "Our hours are 9am-9pm every day"]
        }
   ]
}
```

And I have this Python code so far:

```
import json

inp = input()

with open('Python\intents.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

    for intent in data['intents']:
        for pattern in intent['patterns']:
            if inp in pattern:
```

What I want is, if input is found in one of those patterns, it should print randomized responses from the same tag section based on the input. If I greet, I should receive a greetings back. If I say bye, I should get a bye back, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) to choose one of the responses in `intent["responses"]`.

Comment: I know that, but as I mentioned it in my last paragraph, I want a response based on the input. If I use random.choice(), it will pick one of the responses in the entire JSON list. If input is "hi", in this case it could possibly print "bye", which I don't want.

Comment: No, it won't if you indent the `random.choice` line under `if inp in pattern:` because you are already in the intent block - you're just picking from the `"responses"` key in a certain `intent`, which is where you're searching for the input.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `random.choice` to select a random value from a list.

Here you go:

```
import json
import random

inp = input()

with open('Python\intents.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

    for intent in data['intents']:
        if inp in intent['patterns']:
            print(random.choice(intent['responses']))
            break
```

Couple of improvements I would suggest:

1. Separate data loading from processing
2. Make input case insensitive (you can do this by lower casing your initial patterns and lower casing the input)

```
import json
import random

# Load
with open('Python\intents.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

# Parse
for intent in data['intents']:
    intent['patterns'] = [pattern.lower() for pattern in intent['patterns']]

# Process
inp = input().lower()
for intent in data['intents']:
    if inp in intent['patterns']:
        print(random.choice(intent['responses']))
        break
```

> Do you mind telling me how to do that input should contain minimum two words or more which are also in "patterns? Because I am doing this chatbot in German and our language is a little bit tricky. For example "lower" and "price". Some people ask in Ebay "Hello, can you lower the price" and if I input "Can you lower the price" and patterns include "lower" and "price", it should do x.

For this you can use sets to determine the number of same words between input and pattern.

```
import json
import random

def find_response(inp):
    inp = set(inp.lower().split(' '))
    for intent in data['intents']:
        for proccessed_pattern in intent['processed_patterns']:
            same_words_count = len(inp.intersection(proccessed_pattern))
            if same_words_count >= 2:
                return random.choice(intent['responses'])

with open('Python\intents.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

for intent in data['intents']:
    intent['processed_patterns'] = [set(pattern.lower().split()) for pattern in intent['patterns']]

inp = input()
response = find_response(inp)
print(response)
```

This solution will however lead to a whole series of problems with special characters like `.,!?` and with general words which can be found in any pattern like `the, I, how, when ...`.

Comment: Do you mind telling me how to do that input should contain minimum two words or more which are also in "patterns? Because I am doing this chatbot in German and our language is a little bit tricky. For example "lower" and "price". Some people ask in Ebay "Hello, can you lower the price" and if I input "Can you lower the price" and patterns include "lower" and "price", it should do x.

Comment: What you are trying to do is a rather difficult problem to solve properly. I will expand my answer to also answer this comment (with some drawbacks) for learning purposes. But to do this properly I would suggest using a package like ChatterBot: https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/.

Answer (score 0):

`random.choice` works well here.

Additionally, it might be good eliminate the `tag` key altogether and create nested dicts with the `tag` as the key.

```
import json
import random

inp = input()

with open('Python\intents.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

# no need to keep the file open here, changed indent level
for intent in data['intents']:
    if inp in intent['patterns']:
        print(random.choice(intent['responses']))
```